# Microsoft LifeCam VX-800 stopped working on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, camera

My Microsoft Lifecam VX-800 stopped working without any plausible reason. `lsusb` identifies the camera with the name "Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Venus USB2.0 Camera". Another unusual thing is that the camera's green light is always turned on (this didn't happen when it was still working).

I didn't install any new software, update anything, or change any OS configurations. What could have broken things?